# JavaFX: getChildren().addAll() argument not applicable

Tags: javafx

I have a basic question for JavaFX but coudn't figure it out. For HBox, When I'm using getChildren().addAll() for Label and ImageView, I get the following message:

```
The method addAll(int, Collection<? extends Node>) in the type List<Node> is not applicable for the argument (Label, ImageView[])
```

I'm not sure what's the issue. I can use normally if its (TextField, ImageView[]), but it doesn't work for (Label, ImageView[]).

This is my simplified code:

```
ImageView[] imagesRow = new ImageView[2];
Image[] img = new Image[2];
String title = "Result";

img[0] = new Image("sample1.png", 60, 35, true, true);
img[1] = new Image("sample2.png", 60, 35, true, true);

imagesRow[0] = new ImageView();
imagesRow[1] = new ImageView();

imagesRow[0].setImage (img[0]);
imagesRow[1].setImage (img[1]);

Label label = new Label();
label.setText(title + ": ");

// Create horizontal box 
HBox box = new HBox();
box.setPadding(new Insets(20, 5 , 2, 50));
box.getChildren().addAll(label, imagesRow); // issue here
```

May I seek the reason and what should I do instead to align label and image horizontally?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I understand it, a `Collection` needs to be of one type (or inheriting from a common type). So when you try to insert a `Label` and an array as part of the same `Collection`, you can't do that. An array does not inherit a common parent with `Label`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. But when I do `addAll (imagesRow)`, it works without problem, and when I do `addAll (label, imagesRow)` then it prompts error. That's why I'm wondering how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Collection` needs to be of one type (or inheriting from a common parent somewhere in the heirarchy).

A `Label` is a type of `Node` and therefore anything else you try to pass as a part of the `Collection` parameter must also be a `Node`. An array is obviously not.

In your case, you would need to use two calls to populate the children of the `HBox`:

```
box.getChildren().add(label);
box.getChildren().addAll(imagesRow);
```

The reason you can call `addAll(imagesRow)` without a problem is because with only the one argument, you're only passing in **one** `Collection`, an array.

By calling `addAll(label, imagesRow)`, you're telling Java that you're passing a `Collection` of one type, but you actually passed it a `Node` and an array.